# Как отладить/отловить причину завершения spring/java приложения?

Tags: java, spring

Мое spring приложение корректно закрывается само после 5 минут нормальной работы.  Как мне вообще отловить причину такого странного поведения?

То есть я запускаю, 4 минуты 50 секунд минут ровно секунда в секунду (таймер ожидания запуска в конфигурациях) оно работает и потом завершает работу. (апд: тут в комментариях мой код запустили - он работает нормально, у меня- завершается) все еще остается вопрос где найти причину завершения,  как отловить ошибку с которой закрывается
я пробовала на локальной машине, на свежем виртуальном сервере - итог один.

Так выглядит лог:

```
2020-01-08 15:29:12.189  INFO 3684 --- [lication.main()] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2020-01-08 15:29:12.190 DEBUG 3684 --- [lication.main()] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding PropertySource 'server.ports' with highest search precedence
2020-01-08 15:29:12.197  INFO 3684 --- [lication.main()] e.h.u.UserManagingApiApplication         : Started UserManagingApiApplication in 9.338 seconds (JVM running for 13.59)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  05:02 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-08T15:34:02Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-01-08 15:34:02.737  INFO 3684 --- [       Thread-4] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6f363a58: startup date [Wed Jan 08 15:29:03 UTC 2020]; root of context hierarchy
2020-01-08 15:34:02.749  INFO 3684 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2020-01-08 15:34:02.750  INFO 3684 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2020-01-08 15:34:02.750  INFO 3684 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
2020-01-08 15:34:02.750  INFO 3684 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : stopped _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
2020-01-08 15:34:02.751  INFO 3684 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-01-08 15:34:02.752  INFO 3684 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2020-01-08 15:34:02.752  INFO 3684 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2020-01-08 15:34:02.761  INFO 3684 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-01-08 15:34:02.764  INFO 3684 --- [       Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-01-08 15:34:02.776  INFO 3684 --- [       Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
ubuntu@map-demo:~/zmap_web/user-managing-api$
```

Comment: Может какой Scheduler хулиганет. И вы приложили лог где написано что сборка у вас длится 5 мин

Comment: @Z.John
я уже поставила на стерильно чистый сервак. Да, есть подозрения что происки конкурентов - потому что ну не может быть ровно 4-50, потому думаю - есть ли способ как то отловить-отладить причину

Comment: проект в открытом доступе? ссылку дать можете?

Comment: https://github.com/mira13/stackTest

для запуска нужно создать пустую бд схему с именем havana (flyway plugin ее сам заполнит на старте) и в application.properties конечно логин пароль к бд. Стартую простым mvn spring-boot:start Спасибо огромное за участие

Comment: @Mira попробуйте запустить через IDE.

Comment: @Mira в `pom.xml` у плагина `spring-boot-maven-plugin` уберите блок `configuration`.

Comment: @Tsyklop да,  вы частично правы,  без него падает сразу.  с ним раньше работало нормально (иногда надо было подождать подольше чтоб подключится к бд) . Теперь Наверно проблема в другом.  Странно что эти 5 мин работает нормально

Comment: @Mira с какой ошибкой падает?

Comment: Без ошибки, просто закрывается корректно.  Лог в вопросе.  Debug включен.  В этом и вопрос как увидеть почему

Comment: Вам нужен лог Tomcat, на котором запускается приложение

Comment: @Z.John включила логи томката logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=DEBUG
logging.level.org.apache.catalina=DEBUG ничего нового они не показали.  Сервер успешно стартует (как в логах вопроса) и тут же закрывается

Comment: У меня он писал что не может к БД подключиться, задайте в конфиге пароль для пользователя. После этого у меня все заработало. `spring.datasource.password=...`

Comment: @Z.John  у меня к базе подключается нормально, она и есть без пароля,    У вас  версия с таймером она работает 5 минут потом выключится.  Таймер в pom.xml - spring boot plugin - configuration.  Без таймера завершится сразу.

Comment: Она уже мин 15 работает, сейчас pom поправлю -попробую

Comment: У меня запускается. У вас на github последняя версия? Больше ничего не меняли?

Comment: @Z.John ничего, только что ее специально туда скопировала. Запускается она у меня нормально и работает нормально ровно 4-50 по таймеру. Раньше работала нормально, думаю не закинули ли мне вредоносного софта.  И как же мне отладить причину почему?

Comment: Да, у меня работает постоянно - пока не остановлю

Comment: @Z.John и какие есть способы отладки - отловить причину почему у меня завершается? (а раньше как у вас работало нормально) Логи какие то дополнительные?

Comment: Думаю, я догадался. Вы запускаете spring-boot:start ? а надо spring-boot:run. Сейчас нажал spring-boot:start получилась картина как у вас

Comment: @Z.John даа!! спасибо огромное все заработало! Если оформите как ответ - отмечу верным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы запускаете spring-boot:start, запускайте приложение через spring-boot:run  - так все работает :)